# Differentiating deployment ENV in properties file using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

So i have a Python script which does grant access (whitelist) users in websphere.
I have integrated this with Jenkins and a properties file in GIT that has list of users.
When I execute the jenkins job which runs on a slave machine as restricted in the setup.
What i now need to do is to differentiate the deployment env from non-prod and prod.

Comment: Hi. Can you be a bit more explicit, what this magic python script does, what the special thing about the restricted slave/agent machine is and what in that properties file is.. There are just too many variables as if we could tell you _the_ solution.

Comment: So the python reads the properties file(has user name csv format with app name) from git and builds a Websphere command and executes.
The slave/agent is where the python script resides the WebSphere servers.

Comment: P.S -> when i run the job with the git filename as appName.TST.properties it should run on TST slave nodes and appName.PRD.properties it should on on PRD slave node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whitelists / passwords for prod Systems should not be stored as part of the repo but somewhere else on the target machine / prod System or even as a [manual input](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) to the target location if you do not deploy that frequently.

This being said, you can use [conditional pipeline steps](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/). The block after the **when** keyword will be executed only if the expression evaluates to true: Examples: `env.TARGET_SYSTEM = 'prod' or GIT_BRANCH.startsWith("PROD")`

You can have a block for ***non-prod*** systems where you copy the whitelist file to the apps target dir, and an other one for ***prod*** ones where you just check for the existence of the file (if it does not exist you can request a manual interaction and send out an email to copy the file here and there)

In case for you it is totally fine to have production data as part of the repo then simply use good old filename convention:

```
sh "cp whitelist.${params.TARGET_SYSTEM}.properties /my/target/dir"
```

where filenames are like: whitelist.non-prod.properties and whitelist.prod.properties . TARGET_SYSTEM is a parameter of the job

Comment: But the problem is i have 2 agents when the file name is whitelist.non-prod.properties it should run on prod agent. And the other way around.

Comment: in the agent section -- make the name of the agent a parameter ..aka instead of 
           agent("master") { .... } agent("$TARGET")